# Using SQLite, how do I find instances of "A,B" where "A,C" and "B,C" aren't true?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following tables:

Table 1:

```
col1 | col2
 A1  |  B1
 A2  |  B2
```

Table 2:

```
col3 | col4
 A1  |  C1
 B1  |  C1
 A2  |  C2
 B2  |  C3
```

I want to find instances where A and B are paired in the first table, i.e. "A1 and B1", but only where A and B don't both have the same C.

I realize I probably haven't worded this very well. In the above tables I would want to return: A2 and B2 because they're paired in the first table, but in the second they have different C's. A1 and B1 would not be returned because they both have C1 in the second table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you can use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.col1 = t2.col3
JOIN table2 t3
  ON t1.col2 = t3.col3
WHERE t2.col4 <> t3.col4;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/388192)**</kbd>

I've assumed that all your columns are `NOT NULL`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't fully understand though - where does t3 come from?

Comment: @07acrow Look carefully. I join table1 to table2 twice and use aliasses t2 and t3 to refer to them